# How do I cite — in APA style — a Creative Commons licensed image retrieved from Wikimedia Commons?

Tags: citations, citation-style, creative-commons

Suppose I wish to use this image in my paper: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_white_tiger.jpg

```
+--------------+
|              |
|  IMAGE HERE  |
|              |
+--------------+

Figure 1: A white tiger in captivity (Morin, 2018).
```

How do I properly cite the image in the references section?

My attempt:

Format:
John, D. (Year). Official description. Publisher. Retrieved on Month Date, Year. https://www.example.com/image-source.jpg. License.

> Morin, B. (2018). Standing white tiger (Bengal tiger species ) with open mouth, at Singapore Zoo. Wikimedia Commons. Retrieved October 8, 2020. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_white_tiger.jpg. CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

Suppose the English description does not exist; only the French description exists. How should the citation look like when there is only an official description in French? My attempt:

> Morin, B. (2018). Tigre blanc (espèce Tigre du Bengale ), la gueule ouverte, au zoo de Singapour [Standing white tiger (Bengal tiger species ) with open mouth, at Singapore Zoo]. Wikimedia Commons. Retrieved October 8, 2020. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_white_tiger.jpg. CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

Are my citations of Wikimedia Commons Creative Commons licensed images correct in APA style?

Answer (score 1):

Section 12.18 of APA 7 states:

> To write a copyright attribution,
>
> - state whether the material was reprinted or adapted (use "From" for reprintings and "Adapted from" for adaptations);
> - provide the title, author, year of publication, and source of the material;
> - indicate the material's copyright status...; and
> - provide the permission statement as requested by the copyright holder if permission was sought and obtained.
>
> Place the copyright attribution as follows:
>
> - For a reprinted or adapted ... image ..., place the copyright attribution at the end of the general note for the table or figure ...
>
> (American Psychological Association, 2020, p. 389)

In other words, the copyright attribution goes into the **general note** for the figure, not in the references section.

As an aside, APA 7 has some differences from APA 6, one of which is that you no longer use "Retrieved from" unless the source is likely to change often (as in a Wiki page).

For the references section, visual works are covered in section 10.14. I would do something like this (with hanging indent):

Morin, B. (2018). *Standing white tiger* [Photograph]. Wikimedia Commons. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_white_tiger.jpg